# How to periodically flush in-memory rasters with GDAL Python bindings?

Tags: python, gdal

I don't like to post highly speculative questions but I don't really know how I can test my problem to get more concrete observations. So I will try to explain this as best as I can:

I have a script which processes lots of small rasters which are created at the various levels of a recursive workflow. Sometimes Python will crash, sometimes it won't. However I have noticed that on the occasions where it does not crash, I get an output at the end of the script like this:

```
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/03721b5c-9930-496a-a3b8-0c4a28984381/03721b5c-9930-496a-a3b8-0c4a28984381. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/039b9b86-3113-4650-9da0-508d19a36bc3/039b9b86-3113-4650-9da0-508d19a36bc3. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/05c2e2ac-cae2-4910-a004-bf345fc49a5c/05c2e2ac-cae2-4910-a004-bf345fc49a5c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/06fb161d-beb7-48cb-9997-90d21d96ec1c/06fb161d-beb7-48cb-9997-90d21d96ec1c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/06ff1c1e-beac-43d8-b950-f873a5b68a65/06ff1c1e-beac-43d8-b950-f873a5b68a65. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/08272ae8-d7bd-4262-b763-386814b2817f/08272ae8-d7bd-4262-b763-386814b2817f. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/08a4176c-81df-48e9-9ec4-fb2ccfe68829/08a4176c-81df-48e9-9ec4-fb2ccfe68829. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/102be205-9324-4bdd-8e22-4c9b352acf79/102be205-9324-4bdd-8e22-4c9b352acf79. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/10713f27-7fbc-4b85-a85d-e65a8e71a4fe/10713f27-7fbc-4b85-a85d-e65a8e71a4fe. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/15b9022b-d6ed-4d26-94eb-81ac7fc0b739/15b9022b-d6ed-4d26-94eb-81ac7fc0b739. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/1b6a063f-9676-456e-bd70-5d8bad0569e6/1b6a063f-9676-456e-bd70-5d8bad0569e6. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/1c4b7e65-8179-4d49-9162-11c80371961b/1c4b7e65-8179-4d49-9162-11c80371961b. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/220466aa-0e87-4cf5-a570-435f8443355a/220466aa-0e87-4cf5-a570-435f8443355a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/22e2a143-4eaa-4907-af26-8a1969e44e65/22e2a143-4eaa-4907-af26-8a1969e44e65. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/25023c9c-7dbb-4271-b24f-d9719afe0dc1/25023c9c-7dbb-4271-b24f-d9719afe0dc1. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/28544b40-bc00-40c8-a39f-6be9b5498896/28544b40-bc00-40c8-a39f-6be9b5498896. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/2a371692-0d9e-4ae2-80a0-64d5b270fca1/2a371692-0d9e-4ae2-80a0-64d5b270fca1. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/2e61395e-4fdd-4016-953e-ec3de1c0e95d/2e61395e-4fdd-4016-953e-ec3de1c0e95d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/2f5ed138-251c-450e-a410-ac3d13c7829c/2f5ed138-251c-450e-a410-ac3d13c7829c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/2fd657a5-71a3-4e7c-b5f3-3dc6c30c8339/2fd657a5-71a3-4e7c-b5f3-3dc6c30c8339. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/31a99519-0323-4df1-ae15-aa407d21d295/31a99519-0323-4df1-ae15-aa407d21d295. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/342b8d8f-6984-414e-ab1c-c4c524554dbd/342b8d8f-6984-414e-ab1c-c4c524554dbd. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/34a3d4d8-c5c2-48de-a4bb-bc93a1d3d464/34a3d4d8-c5c2-48de-a4bb-bc93a1d3d464. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/34c8f182-1881-43c6-9086-e0a7be47332e/34c8f182-1881-43c6-9086-e0a7be47332e. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/360d9941-0d57-49bb-b888-2d620d045056/360d9941-0d57-49bb-b888-2d620d045056. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/38a1e910-5b23-4eba-8346-11cf1f6980c8/38a1e910-5b23-4eba-8346-11cf1f6980c8. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3964ae63-1b1f-418b-b353-358211fdf553/3964ae63-1b1f-418b-b353-358211fdf553. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3aff87b8-a670-4b7d-9c47-723256a4a080/3aff87b8-a670-4b7d-9c47-723256a4a080. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3bd8b9a6-8139-4d30-9243-ff0c2cc20da6/3bd8b9a6-8139-4d30-9243-ff0c2cc20da6. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3c5514f2-a4f1-4513-8d60-0705f3d1d7f1/3c5514f2-a4f1-4513-8d60-0705f3d1d7f1. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3e15c0cb-7fbb-490f-b791-b43299413b7a/3e15c0cb-7fbb-490f-b791-b43299413b7a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3e1f6b84-f100-4bf5-97c2-dbc2a0544cce/3e1f6b84-f100-4bf5-97c2-dbc2a0544cce. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3ecdc9b3-9ff9-43a4-8017-d5fe54821d6c/3ecdc9b3-9ff9-43a4-8017-d5fe54821d6c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/3f9aa4dd-c1d6-4085-acea-fc76c7e9f0ea/3f9aa4dd-c1d6-4085-acea-fc76c7e9f0ea. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/419a12fa-30ab-4048-a006-2210aef8224e/419a12fa-30ab-4048-a006-2210aef8224e. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/41b01638-b7a0-474c-9e0b-c72fff585ef3/41b01638-b7a0-474c-9e0b-c72fff585ef3. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/44cd347d-774e-473b-8987-a92ca4d9b266/44cd347d-774e-473b-8987-a92ca4d9b266. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/45aadcc0-b322-42ce-84b7-a0aae069a49c/45aadcc0-b322-42ce-84b7-a0aae069a49c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/461cc929-c62a-47a9-9ba1-22b71726d5a3/461cc929-c62a-47a9-9ba1-22b71726d5a3. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/494784ae-8e44-415f-90c9-2d41c491b52d/494784ae-8e44-415f-90c9-2d41c491b52d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/4b07fb9c-a76c-4baf-9a0f-590a5791ee6d/4b07fb9c-a76c-4baf-9a0f-590a5791ee6d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/4f5af6a3-e09b-48f5-ab5e-c17ad3a3653e/4f5af6a3-e09b-48f5-ab5e-c17ad3a3653e. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/5109d606-7bb6-4a56-8eb0-3d42ba7c3df6/5109d606-7bb6-4a56-8eb0-3d42ba7c3df6. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/53c9bcd1-de38-4f9e-84c1-b42bc7f96988/53c9bcd1-de38-4f9e-84c1-b42bc7f96988. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/548be976-2eda-49bf-9e54-ac7ff87d5eee/548be976-2eda-49bf-9e54-ac7ff87d5eee. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/57c13ba4-698c-48af-9adb-eac5a6d35225/57c13ba4-698c-48af-9adb-eac5a6d35225. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/5b2a5593-2d58-404c-bddb-aaaa7557deff/5b2a5593-2d58-404c-bddb-aaaa7557deff. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/5e05697c-68e9-481f-b59f-37eb01c1993d/5e05697c-68e9-481f-b59f-37eb01c1993d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/5e198ab3-e96d-494d-9d44-8055281a1e21/5e198ab3-e96d-494d-9d44-8055281a1e21. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/6026c9b0-3e36-4e51-9acb-ae2b0fe4ea3e/6026c9b0-3e36-4e51-9acb-ae2b0fe4ea3e. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/608f74b8-7748-4273-9823-9128a77a074d/608f74b8-7748-4273-9823-9128a77a074d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/65dcb16a-9b7b-4f27-90ab-f79f98d96eda/65dcb16a-9b7b-4f27-90ab-f79f98d96eda. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/67bc961c-150f-4b6e-9590-483d530ffe85/67bc961c-150f-4b6e-9590-483d530ffe85. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/719aa72f-bf9a-45a8-b81a-21d7815a1eff/719aa72f-bf9a-45a8-b81a-21d7815a1eff. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/725c7ea9-2b40-431d-a11f-30614c09c732/725c7ea9-2b40-431d-a11f-30614c09c732. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/797f677d-5584-424b-b77f-8da22063f530/797f677d-5584-424b-b77f-8da22063f530. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/7c746ea3-0fce-4938-baef-4ffa8a87ad29/7c746ea3-0fce-4938-baef-4ffa8a87ad29. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/7cd994cd-682f-407f-9d03-6d52e337c191/7cd994cd-682f-407f-9d03-6d52e337c191. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/7fd7fa3f-5f6c-4af4-9e8f-6d7684d84f25/7fd7fa3f-5f6c-4af4-9e8f-6d7684d84f25. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/83b55469-bbbc-4161-ba8d-b5753a42a68a/83b55469-bbbc-4161-ba8d-b5753a42a68a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/88588237-e949-4d2f-b686-e494d1e8d933/88588237-e949-4d2f-b686-e494d1e8d933. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/8bc4d03e-4c0d-420e-a780-02f56a737fcb/8bc4d03e-4c0d-420e-a780-02f56a737fcb. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/8c87ae13-e9c4-474f-bbd6-7b747a9288f2/8c87ae13-e9c4-474f-bbd6-7b747a9288f2. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/90782469-3bc5-4acf-ae49-6eb7137fbeec/90782469-3bc5-4acf-ae49-6eb7137fbeec. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/90f86b67-cd78-4ece-a36a-c73d3cf56ef4/90f86b67-cd78-4ece-a36a-c73d3cf56ef4. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/91566549-6137-448e-a0de-fad4bb7723f4/91566549-6137-448e-a0de-fad4bb7723f4. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9962ea55-c459-497a-bfbc-530a18ece1a2/9962ea55-c459-497a-bfbc-530a18ece1a2. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9c01a8f1-c0b8-4c72-9627-625c3b583eee/9c01a8f1-c0b8-4c72-9627-625c3b583eee. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9c561840-eb78-42f4-8183-cfd500e7cc53/9c561840-eb78-42f4-8183-cfd500e7cc53. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9cb4678a-2a05-4177-8cbd-6296b59af884/9cb4678a-2a05-4177-8cbd-6296b59af884. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9d06e9e7-9dcd-4377-99a3-9ff7af24f47a/9d06e9e7-9dcd-4377-99a3-9ff7af24f47a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/9eaa3016-d3f3-4948-be04-4e83f9826891/9eaa3016-d3f3-4948-be04-4e83f9826891. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/a2b60fb8-6d8d-487c-993c-7a9259721b30/a2b60fb8-6d8d-487c-993c-7a9259721b30. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/a50ac847-cfaa-4b15-8e86-c6c958c53ce5/a50ac847-cfaa-4b15-8e86-c6c958c53ce5. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/a818cf09-0de9-41ec-bcf4-62bd69275485/a818cf09-0de9-41ec-bcf4-62bd69275485. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/a9d07236-fd9c-43e1-9546-3e237c7779be/a9d07236-fd9c-43e1-9546-3e237c7779be. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/ac6a307e-8129-4714-8b7c-75ea90546721/ac6a307e-8129-4714-8b7c-75ea90546721. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/aededf52-2574-44dd-b0b9-852288b15165/aededf52-2574-44dd-b0b9-852288b15165. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/afcb85f3-0849-4f5b-aa9a-e8e5ea21e0fb/afcb85f3-0849-4f5b-aa9a-e8e5ea21e0fb. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b13b6a05-bf50-4eee-9569-cfb99e4448c4/b13b6a05-bf50-4eee-9569-cfb99e4448c4. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b2616fa3-0bfa-4d22-b0a0-f277686c7926/b2616fa3-0bfa-4d22-b0a0-f277686c7926. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b2cffb6c-c78e-4da4-b820-c119f910e771/b2cffb6c-c78e-4da4-b820-c119f910e771. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b50f8afe-8c9b-49da-96bf-4b8bd5df2741/b50f8afe-8c9b-49da-96bf-4b8bd5df2741. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b5f227b8-e36a-42b5-bf8e-a7115a5a3ab0/b5f227b8-e36a-42b5-bf8e-a7115a5a3ab0. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/b6b72577-d8f1-438e-8e5f-fd79e8752f0b/b6b72577-d8f1-438e-8e5f-fd79e8752f0b. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/bd0a82a6-9435-48c7-9903-b3e3d549e40a/bd0a82a6-9435-48c7-9903-b3e3d549e40a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/bff0298a-19fb-4869-9afd-bf1d2acdc137/bff0298a-19fb-4869-9afd-bf1d2acdc137. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/c4526216-9a03-430a-a6d0-e8d896f186c9/c4526216-9a03-430a-a6d0-e8d896f186c9. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/c5352189-aa7a-4dfa-8035-731b3e7d46e7/c5352189-aa7a-4dfa-8035-731b3e7d46e7. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/ce7a98a9-ac24-46f7-af4c-8b10ff4b980a/ce7a98a9-ac24-46f7-af4c-8b10ff4b980a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/cf7f0881-364f-4034-ac81-6c5581e7e063/cf7f0881-364f-4034-ac81-6c5581e7e063. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/cff46c80-d123-4ca9-8ce0-ded0531c0c8b/cff46c80-d123-4ca9-8ce0-ded0531c0c8b. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/d5a332e3-d84d-4e15-8744-d4d029fba705/d5a332e3-d84d-4e15-8744-d4d029fba705. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/d5a4dd6c-a56c-4b3e-a54d-e268a656abf6/d5a4dd6c-a56c-4b3e-a54d-e268a656abf6. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/d6095bdc-977e-47c8-b844-dba537c8f307/d6095bdc-977e-47c8-b844-dba537c8f307. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/dad3218d-4253-4b80-9dde-4adc0e3ad5bd/dad3218d-4253-4b80-9dde-4adc0e3ad5bd. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/dcef407f-e8f0-4d29-b687-72172e9d03a0/dcef407f-e8f0-4d29-b687-72172e9d03a0. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e00286bb-79b3-4e6d-93e4-fc1f5d0af057/e00286bb-79b3-4e6d-93e4-fc1f5d0af057. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e0bd8021-1664-435d-b9bb-533c50c7db68/e0bd8021-1664-435d-b9bb-533c50c7db68. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e1480a74-2b32-488c-9634-38e9f8703642/e1480a74-2b32-488c-9634-38e9f8703642. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e3820f13-46da-471d-a2a6-92b158558a0f/e3820f13-46da-471d-a2a6-92b158558a0f. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e549a4e7-3aa6-42c7-bda9-c1c666c3b82c/e549a4e7-3aa6-42c7-bda9-c1c666c3b82c. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e54fed43-21be-48f4-868e-e933f5f863e5/e54fed43-21be-48f4-868e-e933f5f863e5. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e6721a8e-8be6-4fed-8b0e-6787107b9a72/e6721a8e-8be6-4fed-8b0e-6787107b9a72. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/e6a0a559-3e5c-43a0-a82b-75141065217d/e6a0a559-3e5c-43a0-a82b-75141065217d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/ea4071d7-abec-463f-b3c8-cde2f36a365a/ea4071d7-abec-463f-b3c8-cde2f36a365a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/ea483b93-ea0c-4f31-9294-e9e60e373195/ea483b93-ea0c-4f31-9294-e9e60e373195. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/ed457d2f-5733-4282-aa31-f6751affbf11/ed457d2f-5733-4282-aa31-f6751affbf11. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f125bdd4-9367-4cd3-8dc9-7261aa1d663f/f125bdd4-9367-4cd3-8dc9-7261aa1d663f. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f260fc7e-d583-42c7-907d-e90c6bd46592/f260fc7e-d583-42c7-907d-e90c6bd46592. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f40222ec-7248-4ea2-9834-db3bdfd3880d/f40222ec-7248-4ea2-9834-db3bdfd3880d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f437b626-e902-4b8c-a4e5-998760e54db5/f437b626-e902-4b8c-a4e5-998760e54db5. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f44d822b-38ab-4ff6-bf79-bce34c0a1686/f44d822b-38ab-4ff6-bf79-bce34c0a1686. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f69022df-7f31-4417-937f-56f4a28faa55/f69022df-7f31-4417-937f-56f4a28faa55. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f7fc2f9b-98d8-4345-94d5-c90f8cc5526d/f7fc2f9b-98d8-4345-94d5-c90f8cc5526d. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f83e3e68-5ead-46e1-90b7-dbd00f6d5172/f83e3e68-5ead-46e1-90b7-dbd00f6d5172. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/f9635ed1-1b81-4840-ba73-ebd56804a932/f9635ed1-1b81-4840-ba73-ebd56804a932. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/fac8a640-67ba-4427-b138-a04437179333/fac8a640-67ba-4427-b138-a04437179333. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/fc744d04-4bd5-47eb-9de7-c7184c2d3d7a/fc744d04-4bd5-47eb-9de7-c7184c2d3d7a. deleted with 1 references.
Warning 1: Memory file /vsimem/fe61124c-97eb-42df-a391-74f8566e6efb/fe61124c-97eb-42df-a391-74f8566e6efb. deleted with 1 references.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think that these warnings are being generated by GDAL because I am creating many rasters in memory. As such I think that it may be prudent for me to occasionally take a break from processing and flush these in-memory rasters, because once I finish processing one, I do not need it anymore. Is it possible to do this in GDAL (Python bindings)? If so, how?

Comment: It looks more like you are not closing or disposing or deleting  them - from my (limited) C++ memories this means that the memory is not recovered. See https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html#closing-the-dataset

Comment: @IanTurton I think you are right. I am creating an in-memory raster with rasterio and I think that I have neglected to close it when I am finished. I will have a deeper look later today and report back.